# How can I get this brute force algorithm to check letters incrementally

Tags: c, brute-force

For this assignment I have to use pthreads in C to make a brute force password cracker.

The code below uses for loops to generate a 6 letter password (ideally 8 letters long) and then I use crypt_r to hash it and compare it with a hash and salt that I give the program at execution.

The hash and salt are taken in at the start, stored in a struct called dataStr which then feeds it to pthreadCreate.

It seems pretty straight forward but even when I memset the array to a null terminating char, at execution the program still sets the whole thing to 'aaaaaa'. The problem with this is that it ignores passwords that are 1-4 chars long.

**Here is the data structure I'm using:**

```
typedef struct {

    char * hash;            //hashed code given in argv[1]
    char * salt;            //salt for hashed code given in argv[2]

    int start;              //starting char in alphabet for first letter
    int end;                //ending char in alphabet for first letter

    int id;                 //thread id

} dataStruct;
```

Size definitions :

```
//Definitions
#define PW_SIZE 8
#define ALPHABET_SIZE 66
#define HASH_MAX_SIZE 128
```

**and here is the code itself**

```
void * thread(void * arg) {

    struct timespec start, finish;          //Data structure for time.h library
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start); //Start chronometer
    double elapsed;

    struct crypt_data* cdata = (struct crypt_data *)malloc(sizeof(struct crypt_data));
    cdata->initialized = 0;

    dataStruct dataStr = *((dataStruct*)(arg)); //receive structure in arguement

    const char * alphabet = get_alphabet();     //create alphabet

    bool pw_found = false;                      //boolean used for 
    int retDone = 1;

    char * pwd = malloc(PW_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    memset(pwd, '\0', PW_SIZE);

    int i,j,k,l,m,n;

    for (i = dataStr.start; i <= dataStr.end; i++) {            
        for (j = 0; j <= ALPHABET_SIZE; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k <= ALPHABET_SIZE; k++) {
                for (l = 0; l <= ALPHABET_SIZE; l++) {
                    for (m = 0; m <= ALPHABET_SIZE; m++) {
                        for (n = 0; n <= ALPHABET_SIZE; n++) {

                            if (pw_found) {
                                clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);        
                                elapsed = finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
                                elapsed += (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0; 
                                printf("Time elapsed : %f sec(s) \n\n", elapsed);   //Time

                                pthread_exit(&retDone);                                 
                            }                           

                            pwd[0] = alphabet[i];   
                            pwd[1] = alphabet[j];   
                            pwd[2] = alphabet[k];
                            pwd[3] = alphabet[l];
                            pwd[4] = alphabet[m];
                            pwd[5] = alphabet[n];

                            printf("%s\n", pwd);

                            char * hash = crypt_r(pwd, dataStr.salt, cdata);

                            if (strcmp(hash, dataStr.hash) == 0) {
                                printf("\nPassword     : %s\n", pwd);
                                pw_found = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }                       
    }

    pthread_exit(&retDone); 
}
```

Here's what it produces at execution:

[image]

I'd like to learn how I can change the 6 loops somehow in order to get the program to first only search in 1 letter chars, then 2, then 3 and increment from there.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot !

PS - I don't mind emailing someone the code for a global view.

Comment: You do not show the size definitions etc, but usually a loop such as `for (j = 0; j <= ALPHABET_SIZE; j++)` followed by `pwd[1] = alphabet[j];` is over by 1, a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Too broad. And don't post images of text.

Comment: Well, they help improve your question to follow site rules. Which in terms increases the chance of your question to get an answer. I'd say they are very well constructive.

Comment: When I see 6 inner loops there is something  wrong In the design

Comment: @EdHeal I sat down and tried to code it recursively but I couldn't figure it out... please help me !

Comment: Most likely it should be `j < ALPHABET_SIZE` otherwise this is basically the correct approach, it's how brute force is done with many loops. There are minor improvements to make, but most of the work is done by `crypt_r` which will slow down the program.

Comment: [don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers can be used to accomplish this. `ppw` will point to somewhere in the `pw` array. `pch` will point to somewhere in the `characters` array. Incrementing(++) and decrementing(--) the pointers moves the pointers within the elements of their respective arrays. Dereferencing(*) gives access to the values that the pointers point to. `used` is the number of elements in `pw` that have been used. It starts at 0 for the first element and increases toward `SIZE`. `characters` may be modified to include the valid letters, numbers and symbols. Just be careful that there are no duplicates. If, for example, the letter `u` appears more than once, the program will get in an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 5

int main( void)
{
    char pw[SIZE + 1] = "";
    char *ppw = NULL;
    char *pch = NULL;
    char characters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int used = 0;
    int out = 1;
    int last = strlen ( characters) - 1;

    //set pw
    pw[used] = characters[0];
    pw[used + 1] = '\0';

    while ( used < SIZE) {//loop until all elements of pw have been used
        ppw = &pw[used];//set ppw to point to last used element of pw
        while ( ppw >= pw) {//so ppw always points to an element of pw
            if ( ( pch = strchr ( characters, *ppw)) != NULL) {//get pointer into characters for current value that ppw point to
                if ( out) {//print when appropriate
                    printf ( "%s\n", pw);
                }
                if ( pch < &characters[last]) {//pch does not point to last element of characters
                    ++pch;//pch points to next element of characters
                    *ppw = *pch;//set what ppw points to to be the same as what pch points to
                    if ( ppw != &pw[used]) {//ppw is not pointing to last element of pw
                        ppw = &pw[used];
                    }
                    out = 1;//allow printing
                }
                else {//pch is pointing to last element of characters
                    *ppw = characters[0];//set what ppw points to to be the first element of characters
                    ppw--;//ppw points to next lower element of pw. ex from pw[n] to pw[n-1]
                    out = 0;//disable printing
                }
            }
        }//exit loop when ppw points to address less than pw
        used++;//increase elements in use
        memset ( pw, characters[0], used);//reset all elements to first element of characters
        pw[used + 1] = '\0';//just in case, terminate
    }//exit loop when all elements have been used

    exit ( 0);
}
```

This seems to be working. Added two lines to set `out` to 1 and added `used + 1` to the call to memset.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// one more than the desired size
#define SIZE 4

int main( void)
{
    char pw[SIZE] = "";
    char *ppw = NULL;
    char *pch = NULL;
    char characters[] = "abc";
    int used = 0;
    int out = 1;
    int last = strlen ( characters) - 1;

    //set pw as character[0]
    pw[used] = characters[0];
    pw[used + 1] = '\0';

    while ( used < SIZE - 1) {//loop until all elements of pw have been used
        ppw = &pw[used];//set ppw to point to last used element of pw
        out = 1;
        while ( ppw >= pw) {//so ppw always points to an element of pw
            if ( ( pch = strchr ( characters, *ppw)) != NULL) {//get pointer into characters for current value that ppw point to
                if ( out) {//print when appropriate
                    printf ( "%s\n", pw);
                }
                out = 1;
                if ( pch < &characters[last]) {//pch does not point to last element of characters
                    ++pch;//pch points to next element of characters
                    *ppw = *pch;//set what ppw points to to be the same as what pch points to
                    if ( ppw != &pw[used]) {//ppw is not pointing to last element of pw
                        ppw = &pw[used];
                    }
                }
                else {//pch is pointing to last element of characters
                    *ppw = characters[0];//set what ppw points to to be the first element of characters
                    ppw--;//ppw points to next lower element of pw. ex from pw[n] to pw[n-1]
                    out = 0;//disable printing
                }
            }
        }//exit loop when ppw points to address less than pw
        used++;//increase elements in use
        memset ( pw, characters[0], used + 1);//reset all elements to first element of characters
        pw[used + 1] = '\0';//just in case, terminate
    }//exit loop when all elements have been used

    exit ( 0);
}
```

Comment: This is great ! I integrated this within a pthread in order to brute force  a password and it works like a charm. It slows down as we approach 6 chars. So what I did was ask at the start of the program how many threads we want to execute. Based on that, I chop up the alphabet (divided by the number of threads). That way each thread can work on a certain range. 

Would you know where in this code I could set my start and end points for the character generation?

Here's a link to the full code : [Github link](https://github.com/warisp/pw_cracker)

Comment: I use this function to print up to a lenght of 3 for just char * characters = [a,b,c]; and once it gets to cc it never tries aaa,aab,aac. Instead it jumps straight to aba, abb, abc.

Comment: This one is good but there is no need to define SIZE to one more than desired as in your first while condition you do (SIZE - 1). By removing this we can define SIZE to the actual size desired.

Comment: change the last 2 lines to `memset(pw, characters[0], used);` and `pw[used]='\0';`